# Problem in installing matplotlib ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to install python package "matplotlib" in Python 2.7; Ubuntu 16.04
After inserting:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

I get the following error messagge:
[open here error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jcl8.png)
I tried this solution:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev libxft-dev
```

but I got this error:

"Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
E: Impossibile trovare il pacchetto libfreetype6-dev
E: Impossibile trovare il pacchetto libxft-dev"

Comment: Please copy and paste output and error messages from the terminal to your question above. Do not post screenshots of the text.

Comment: No reason to install/build `matplotlib` with pip. This will do : `sudo apt update && sudo apt install python-matplotlib`

Comment: It returns error : Impossible to find python-matplotlib package, maybe I choose a wrong directory?

Answer (score 2):

1. Check in *Software & Updates* -> *Ubuntu Software* tab that the 2nd software source **universe** is enabled.
2. The currently supported releases of Ubuntu are 14.04, 16.04 and 17.10. If you are not running a currently supported release, see the answers to this question: [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release).

Matplotlib is available in the default Ubuntu repositories in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install Matplotlib open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade  
sudo apt install python-matplotlib # for Python 2.x in 18.04 and earlier
```

or

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade  
sudo apt install python3-matplotlib # for Python 3.x
```

Other related packages are python-matplotlib-data python-matplotlib-dbg python-matplotlib-doc and python-matplotlib-venn for Python 2.x and python3-matplotlib-dbg python3-matplotlib-venn for Python 3.x.

Comment: It returns error : Impossible to find python-matplotlib package

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately universe is already enabled. Could it be that I'm working on a wrong directory?

Answer (score 0):

Install python dev file by typing:

```
sudo apt install python-dev
```

Then proceed

Comment: They should probably use the matplotlib from the repositories before trying to install from `pip`.  The only reason they'd have to build from `pip` is if they absolutely must have the newer libraries.